# msbuild error MSB3191: Unable to create directory while publishing in remote server

Tags: .net, msbuild, msdeploy, bamboo, msbuild-task

I am trying to deploy a .Net proj to remote server using Bamboo.
I am new to bamboo
I have used msbuild task

```
msbuild <solution file> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="publishXMLFile"
```

PublishXMLFile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
   <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
   <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
   <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
   <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
   <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
   <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
   <publishUrl>\\<server.IP.Address>\Path\To\Publish\Folder</publishUrl>
   <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Current Logged in user admin privilege in the server, and the folder is shared too.
Still I am getting following error:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(93,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "\\<server.IP.Address>\Path\To\Publish\Folder". Access to the path '\\<server.IP.Address>\Path\To\Publish\Folder' is denied. [C:\bamboo\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\132710426-132546751\Project\Path\ProjectName.csproj]
```

I don't understand what I am missing.

I am new to bamboo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says permission denied. Please check if Bamboo user has permission to create or modify directory. "\\Path\To\Publish\Folder".  It might be missing recursive permissions .